# Any Html control libraries - a visual counterpart to jQuery/Prototype

Tags: html, internet-explorer, firefox, controls, dimensions

jQuery provides a browser neutral library for accessing and manipulating the DOM. This is good.

However I'm looking for a counterpart for the visual side of things - I need to build pixel measured interfaces, without wasting so much time testing and correcting cross browser issues (buttons having crazy margins in IE, or using the wrong box model in FireFox. The many IE and otherwise instances where putting several elements on one line screws up alignment or floats).

Basically I need to be able to plan out interfaces on paper with exact pixel dimensions (for example all textboxes should be exactly 22px high), and then easily translate those designs into Html. In a WinForms world, this is usually straight forward. With html it's anything but, and I find it's worst when it comes to input controls.

What libraries or collections could I use to make this sort of design a reality (outside of just converting everything into Silverlight where that degree of control exists). Javascript is required to be on (AJAX to begin with), so libraries can depend on it entirely for controls.

Some of the components I'm looking for in a uniform style with precise pixel control

Buttons
Textboxes
Dropdowns
ComboBoxes (Dropdown whose text can be edited directly)
Toggle Buttons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternatives include **dojo** (pure-JS) and **GWT** (JS generated from Java). Some may argue that ditching JS altogether and going with the Flash-backed **Flex** is a good option.

Answer (score 1):

Also check out [ExtJS](http://www.extjs.com/). I've used this one extensively and I can vouch for how good it is. Originally it was a fork of the [Yahoo UI Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) (YUI), which Soviut mentioned. Personally, I think it's much better and more usable than the original YUI.

Comment: I could be wrong, but doesn't ExtJS cost money now?  Not that paying a few bucks for a top notch widget library is a bad thing.

Comment: It only costs money if you are writing a closed-source, for-profit commercial web application. If it's just for a regular web site or for an open source web app, it's free. They have a quid pro quo dual licensing scheme. And even if you do have to pay for it, it's well worth it in my opinion. It's not too expensive and there's a lot of premium support you get.

Answer (score 0):

[JQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) is a good extension of JQuery that allows for rich controls like dialogs, drag and droppables, etc.

The [Yahoo Interface Library](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/) is another toolset you can use that may be closer to what you were originally asking for.